# Having trouble with the last line #5 with classification for readomforest classifer

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, prediction

```py
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

predictor_var = ['Gender', 'Married', 'Dependents', 'Education',
       'Self_Employed', 'Loan_Amount_Term', 'Credit_History', 'Property_Area',
        'LoanAmount_log','TotalIncome_log']

classification_model(model, df,predictor_var,outcome_var)
```

Comment: Well can you specify the  trouble that you have, if you have an error please  put the message.

Answer (score 0):

What is `classification_model`? It should be like this:

```py
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

predictor_var = ['Gender', 'Married', 'Dependents', 'Education',
       'Self_Employed', 'Loan_Amount_Term', 'Credit_History', 'Property_Area',
        'LoanAmount_log','TotalIncome_log']

model.fit(df[predictor_var], df[outcome_var])
```